# Is it possible to pass a key as default value in @Value annotation of Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties-file

I have a situation where we are reading one property from properties file and now we have been asked to point to another endpoint and for some time we have to manage both these endpoints unless this new endpoint is tested and validated throughly.

I wanted to handle this situation by adding this newer property in properties file and in the actual class were we are reading this property with `@Value` Annotation the old one can be passed as default with its key as value something like

`@Value("${backend.endpoint:${older.endpoint}}")`. is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do it, I have tested it, my sample code

**code:**

```
@Value("#{ ${spring.myapp.usenewval}  ? '${spring.myapp.newval}' : '${spring.myapp.oldval}}'}")
private String message;
```

**Properties**

```
spring:
  myapp:
    usenewval: false
    newval: hello
    oldval: world.....
```

You can always set spring.myapp.usenewval from outside like

```
java -jar -Dspring.myapp.usenewval=true myapp.jar
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use it like this. (I've personally never done it, so forgive me if I'm wrong)

```
@Configuration
public class PropertyConfiguration {

    @Value("{'${backend.endpoint:${older.endpoint:}}'}")
    private String myValue;
}
```

This `@Value` annotation uses `backend.endpoint`, if it is provided and defaults to `older.endpoint`, if `backend.endpoint` is not provided. 
If neither is provided, the property must be set `null`.

There are other ways to handle this as well. Probably, use `@Value` for both the property and handle in code.

Comment: Thanks I did the same and it worked. Didn't waned to do it from code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is quick fix for you. Kindly refer it.

You can set default value to **@Value annotation of spring** as following.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/your path")
public class MyController {

    @Value("${key:true}")
    private boolean booleanWithDefaultValue;

}
```

Here, I take Boolean variable and set default value as "true".

Hope this solution works.

Comment: Sry but you didn't understood my point and the sample you provided is fr passing default value to a property which most of us might be aware of.